# Who came up with C1V1 = C2V2?

Tags: solutions, reference-request, history-of-chemistry

I was wondering if there is an original scientific publication showing why $C_1V_1 = C_2V_2$ works.

Or perhaps, who described/used it first?

Comment: Maybe this would be better asked on [hsm.se].

Comment: This is probably the extension of the definition of the word "concentration" which was probably used already in the Middle Age, with masses of course (instead of moles}.There is probably no original scientific publication of the definition of the concentration.

Comment: Very difficult to find out because this formula is a special case of general mass balance equations. We will have to find who came up with mass balance equation?

Comment: Even the ancient merchants realized 10 sacks with 50 coins each means 500 coins and that if you put 100 coins into a sack then 5 sacks is enough. Why to scientifically show that it works, when everyday life showed it almost 2000 years ago ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a history question, not a chemistry one.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** It's so simple it was likely never published as a "research result", since it stems quite directly from definitions.

---

It's a small step from the conservation of matter and the definition of concentration.

By definition: $C = \frac{n}{V}$, thus $n = CV$. If you dilute with pure solvent, you don't change the amount of solute that you have, in other words: $n_1 = n_2$. Using the previous equation, you get $C_1V_1 = C_2V_2$.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. OP is asking about the origins of the expressions in terms of history, not why it's mathematically correct.

Comment: My point is that it's so simple it was likely never published as a "research result", since it stems quite directly from definitions.